# How to check whether a value in a column of a table exists or not using SQL code?

Tags: sql, db2

I want to check if an employee number (EX:3424), which is read from a file, exists in a table or not using SQL.

If a record with the given employee number exists, then I have to perform a set of operations. Otherwise, I have to perform some other operations.

I am using DB2-cobol.

Comment: mmmm...have you tried anything yet?? or you just passed on what is told to be done to u, to us?? :)

Comment: "Please solve my issue". No. Show your work then ask questions.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL would be something like this to check for the existence of a given record:

```
SELECT 1
FROM Employee_Table 
WHERE Employee_Number = 3424;
```

This will return one result or none. From there you will be able to tell if a record with the given employee number exists in the database table.

Here is a helpful link on [SQL SELECT Statements](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp).

As for the conditional logic, it would be something like this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Employee_Table WHERE Employee_Number = 3424)
     <Set of operations>
ELSE
     <Some other operations>
```